# Reset all overflows in a page - hide all scrollbars

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a simple way to set in an html page, that is using a bunch of css files, all overflows to hidden ?

The problem is not showing the scrollbar in the page. And we've little control on the content.

Comment: You could do `*{overflow:hidden !important}` but this will bugger up a lot of stuff.

Comment: If all you have is a hammer...

Answer (score 1):

css

```
* {
    overflow: visible !important; /* either this */
    overflow: hidden !important; /* or this , depending on what you prefer */
}
```

Or using jQuery

```
$('*').css({overflow: 'visible'});

// or

$('*').css({overflow: 'hidden'});
```

If you want the content to break out of it's container, then use *visible*, if you want the content that goes out of its container, than use *hidden*.

The `*` is a universal selector in that it selects all elements on a page, including that of all `div`'s, `span`'s, `a`'s, etc.... So if the elements with scroll bars are all of the same type like `div` you could just replace the `$('*')` with `$('div')` to make it more efficient.

Comment: don't forget overflow : auto which hides the bar when there is no overflow

Comment: @AntoineLev True, but from what I understand, he doesn't want any scroll bars to appear at all.